# Error Encountered with AS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got issue on this query kindly assist. i was trying to change the null value to 0 but when I try to run this query it encountered syntax error with AS :

```
select CAST(COALESCE(STATUS AS NVARCHAR(5))) from dbo.amb_cancel_master
```

Comment: use cast( coalesce(status,0) as nvarchar(5))

Comment: @radar: What if Status column also contains some other data than NULL values in the column?

Comment: @PareshJ, if status is not NULL then status is converted to varchar other wise 0 is used.

Comment: @radar: It gives error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value  to data type int.

Comment: @PareshJ, is status column type varchar? Then you don't need cast just coalesce(status,'0') is good

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on Sql Server 2008, you can use ISNULL instead of COALESCE for this situation like:

```
select isnull(CAST(STATUS as NVARCHAR(5)),'0')
from dbo.amb_cancel_master
```